# Access Android sensors via NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, accelerometer, sensors

I need read about 100 samples per second off the accelerometer on a Android, and at a fixed sample rate. The current sensormanager does or offers neither.

I've read [Need to read android sensors really fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916660/need-to-read-android-sensors-really-fast)

He seems to have access to the driver code which made his life easier.

I am curious if anyone has been able to do something like this through the NDK w/o that type of knowledge.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have taken a look at sensor.h, and the API looks very promising; however, a little howto on how to deal with the ASensorEventQueue and ASensorEventQueue_hasEvents and so forth would be -extremely- useful.

Ha!  Update:

This looks a code example for what you want to do.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html

Comment: it works, but using accelerometer keeps a wakelock and prevents suspend mode. Does it make sense ?

Answer (score 3):

Since Android SDK version 9 (for Android > 2.2) it seems to be possible to use the sensors via NDK.

See the STABLE_APIS.html file included in the docs. (Search for "sensor.h"). A mirror of that file is [here](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/STABLE-APIS.html).

Comment: it works, but using accelerometer keeps a wakelock and prevents suspend mode. Does it make sense ?

Answer (score 2):

Example from google https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/sensor-graph.Their code allow you controll SENSOR_REFRESH_RATE_HZ for the accelerometer.Written on c++ and connected to java code  through the NDK.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently worked on a pure C sensor application for android. Using NDK, you can access the sensors on the device without using Java.
Check : https://github.com/PromiseMasango/sensor.
Check : https://github.com/PromiseMasango/Android-NDK-sensor-example.

Comment: i noticed that you read only 50 events/samples, how can we change that to continuously read? i tried replacing it with infinite loop, but it blocks the main thread basically, and putting this loop in a code, i crashed my app on `ALooper_pollAll: No looper for this thread!` error.

Answer (score 1):

Sensors can be read reading directly from system "files" like:

/sys/class/sensors/light_sensor/lux
or
/sys/class/sensors/light_sensor/raw_data

I wonder if there is a more direct way to do it, reading directly from the chip.

Like something in /dev/...