# Is possible get sensor value directly?

Tags: android, sensors

Is it possible to get sensor value directly?

I've read Android Developer page's introduction and search some relative information on Internet
But it seems register the listener is the only way to get sensor value?

But this kind of solution can not meet my project requirement
I need to get the first set of data value even the sensor didn't detect any value change
Use the listener, it can't get any value while no value changed...

Comment: If you want to use the NDK, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200119/access-android-sensors-via-ndk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it seems register the listener is the only way to get sensor value?

Correct. You are welcome to register a listener, then unregister it after you get your first value, if you like. However, bear in mind that sensors tend to be "noisy", and so you may be better served getting a number of sensor readings, then averaging them or otherwise smoothing the data.