# access (faster polling) accelerometer via NativeActivity NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, native, accelerometer, sensors

I've searched for a tutorial/an answer on polling accelerometer faster with NDK but didnt find solver yet. just found an androiddevelopers documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html).

what i need is polling acceleration about 100 samples per second (100Hz), by default my device (Samsung Galaxy SL i9003 with gingerbread 2.3.5) with default SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST can only get about 60 samples persecond (60Hz).
Therefore i tried to access sensor via NativeActivity with NDK by generating .c files that i try to make based on sensor.h and looper.h:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <android/sensor.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <android/looper.h>

#define TAG "accelerondk"
#define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

#define LOOPER_ID 1
#define SAMP_PER_SEC 100 //i've changed to 120, even 10, but nothing happen

void Java_azka_web_ndk_AcceleroNDKActivity_startMonitoring(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz) {
    ASensorManager* sensorManager = ASensorManager_getInstance();

    ALooper* looper = ALooper_forThread();
    if(looper == NULL)
        looper = ALooper_prepare(ALOOPER_PREPARE_ALLOW_NON_CALLBACKS);

    ASensorRef accelerometerSensor = ASensorManager_getDefaultSensor(sensorManager,ASENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    LOGI("accelerometerSensor: %s, vendor: %s", ASensor_getName(accelerometerSensor), ASensor_getVendor(accelerometerSensor));

    ASensorEventQueue* queue = ASensorManager_createEventQueue(sensorManager, looper, LOOPER_ID, NULL, NULL);

    ASensorEventQueue_enableSensor(queue, accelerometerSensor);
    ASensorEventQueue_setEventRate(queue, accelerometerSensor, (1000L/SAMP_PER_SEC)*1000); 

    int ident;//identifier 
    int events;
    while (1) {
        while ((ident=ALooper_pollAll(-1, NULL, &events, NULL) >= 0)) {
            // If a sensor has data, process it now.
            if (ident == LOOPER_ID) {
                ASensorEvent event;
                while (ASensorEventQueue_getEvents(queue, &event, 1) > 0) {
                    LOGI("aaaaaaa accelerometer X = %f y = %f z=%f ", event.acceleration.x, event.acceleration.y, event.acceleration.z);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

so far, i've been able to access accelerometer with NativeActivity, but there is no change with number sample had taken. even when i change ASensorEventQueue_setEventRate big enough or small enough the acceleration recorded still about 60 samples per second (1 samples per 15 milisec)

is there any mistakes in my code? or something that i forget with?

thanks in advance

Comment: have you solve this issue?

Answer (score 10):

I also tried a few things with the sample rate of sensors. I use a Galaxy Nexus.
If I use only the Acc-Sensor the frequency is very low (about 40Hz), but if I use the Acc-Sensor plus the magnetic- and the gyro-sensor the sample rate for each sensor is about 100Hz.
I have no explanation why this happens. Another observation is that the values passed to ASensorEventQueue_setEventRate have no effect. The sample-rate is always the same.
The behaviour is exactly the same for SDK-Code.

Here is the code I used for benchmarking:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/sensor.h>
#include <android/looper.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <time.h>
#define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "TestJNIActivity", __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOOPER_ID 1
#define SAMP_PER_SEC 100

ASensorEventQueue* sensorEventQueue;

int accCounter = 0;
int64_t lastAccTime = 0;

int gyroCounter = 0;
int64_t lastGyroTime = 0;

int magCounter = 0;
int64_t lastMagTime = 0;

/* This is a trivial JNI example where we use a native method
 * to return a new VM String. See the corresponding Java source
 * file located at:
 *
 *   apps/samples/hello-jni/project/src/com/example/HelloJni/HelloJni.java
 */

static int get_sensor_events(int fd, int events, void* data);

struct tm* start;
struct tm* finish;


jstring
Java_de_tum_ndktest_TestJNIActivity_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz )
{
    LOGI("stringFromJNI");
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"Hello from JNI !");
}

void
Java_de_tum_ndktest_TestJNIActivity_sensorValue( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz ) {

    ASensorEvent event;
    int events, ident;
    ASensorManager* sensorManager;
    const ASensor* accSensor;
    const ASensor* gyroSensor;
    const ASensor* magSensor;
    void* sensor_data = malloc(1000);

    LOGI("sensorValue() - ALooper_forThread()");

    ALooper* looper = ALooper_forThread();

    if(looper == NULL)
    {
        looper = ALooper_prepare(ALOOPER_PREPARE_ALLOW_NON_CALLBACKS);
    }

    sensorManager = ASensorManager_getInstance();

    accSensor = ASensorManager_getDefaultSensor(sensorManager, ASENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    gyroSensor = ASensorManager_getDefaultSensor(sensorManager, ASENSOR_TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
    magSensor = ASensorManager_getDefaultSensor(sensorManager, ASENSOR_TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);



    sensorEventQueue = ASensorManager_createEventQueue(sensorManager, looper, 3, get_sensor_events, sensor_data);

    ASensorEventQueue_enableSensor(sensorEventQueue, accSensor);
    ASensorEventQueue_enableSensor(sensorEventQueue, gyroSensor);
    ASensorEventQueue_enableSensor(sensorEventQueue, magSensor);

    //Sampling rate: 100Hz
    int a = ASensor_getMinDelay(accSensor);
    int b = ASensor_getMinDelay(gyroSensor);
    int c = ASensor_getMinDelay(magSensor);
    LOGI("min-delay: %d, %d, %d",a,b,c);
    ASensorEventQueue_setEventRate(sensorEventQueue, accSensor, 100000);
    ASensorEventQueue_setEventRate(sensorEventQueue, gyroSensor, 100000);
    ASensorEventQueue_setEventRate(sensorEventQueue, magSensor, 100000);

    LOGI("sensorValue() - START");
}



static int get_sensor_events(int fd, int events, void* data) {
  ASensorEvent event;
  //ASensorEventQueue* sensorEventQueue;
  while (ASensorEventQueue_getEvents(sensorEventQueue, &event, 1) > 0) {
        if(event.type == ASENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                //LOGI("accl(x,y,z,t): %f %f %f %lld", event.acceleration.x, event.acceleration.y, event.acceleration.z, event.timestamp);
                if(accCounter == 0 || accCounter == 1000)
                    {
                     LOGI("Acc-Time: %lld (%f)", event.timestamp,((double)(event.timestamp-lastAccTime))/1000000000.0);
                     lastAccTime = event.timestamp;
                     accCounter = 0;
                    }

                accCounter++;
        }
        else if(event.type == ASENSOR_TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
                //LOGI("accl(x,y,z,t): %f %f %f %lld", event.acceleration.x, event.acceleration.y, event.acceleration.z, event.timestamp);
                if(gyroCounter == 0 || gyroCounter == 1000)
                    {

                     LOGI("Gyro-Time: %lld (%f)", event.timestamp,((double)(event.timestamp-lastGyroTime))/1000000000.0);
                     lastGyroTime = event.timestamp;
                     gyroCounter = 0;
                    }

                gyroCounter++;
        }
        else if(event.type == ASENSOR_TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
                //LOGI("accl(x,y,z,t): %f %f %f %lld", event.acceleration.x, event.acceleration.y, event.acceleration.z, event.timestamp);
                if(magCounter == 0 || magCounter == 1000)
                    {
                     LOGI("Mag-Time: %lld (%f)", event.timestamp,((double)(event.timestamp-lastMagTime))/1000000000.0);
                     lastMagTime = event.timestamp;
                     magCounter = 0;
                    }

                magCounter++;
        }

  }
  //should return 1 to continue receiving callbacks, or 0 to unregister
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Did you need to create an Activity from which to run this? If so, could you please post that code?

Comment: Sorry, it has been three years since I did this. As far as I remember I used a java-GUI from which I called the JNI-functions. Unfortunately I have no code, but I think it was just a funcion-call. The most complicated part was to setup NDK on my computer (Eclipse).

Comment: I figured it out, thanks. I'll probably update your answer with a few pointers on it.

Comment: it works, but we observed that accelerometers keeps wakelock! Does it make sense ? I thought that only "significant movement sensor" keep wakelock.

Answer (score 3):

Question is a bit old but maybe these two articles will help out a bit for anyone else that stumbles on this question and wonders why bother, or how to optimize the example in the NDK a bit.

These two short articles layout the issues and potential solutions (but no complete source solution)

[Java interfaced sensor performance](http://www.sensorplatforms.com/smartphone-performance-fundamentals-sensor-sampling)

[Native Sampling Improvement](http://www.sensorplatforms.com/native-sampling)

Comment: The links have died. Please try to copy relevant materials into your answer so that information can be preserved.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but given the lack of documentation and articles out there, I thought I'd share my experience. I did all my tests on a Nexus 5X. Your device might be different.

The original code looks right. What isn't obvious from the documentation is that you can only set the event rate *after* enabling the sensor, and that...

**If you re-enable the sensor (say, after onPause() and onResume()), you need to set the event rate again.** If you had a "double enable" like I did in my code (enable()/setEventRate() in init(), but only enable() in onResume()), you will get the default polling rate.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably limited by the speed of the accelerometer hardware in your device. However, you could use [interpolation](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/miscellaneous/interpolation/) to get some extra data points.